# Assertion error or snakemake: error: argument --snakefile/-s: expected one argument when working with Snakemake pipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, snakemake

I am trying to run a Snakemake pipeline, but it either runs into an assertion error or snakemake is unable to find the snakefile for some reason. I am running the pipeline through a Snakefile, a config.yml file, and a bash script.

**Code:**

**Config.yml file:**

```
REPO_DIR="/path/to/pipeline"

REF_FASTA ="$REPO_DIR/data/genome/sacCer3.fasta"

FASTQ_DIR="$REPO_DIR/pipelinetest/fastq"
OUTPUT_DIR="$REPO_DIR/pipelineoutput"
ANC_DIR="$REPO_DIR/pipelineanc"

LOG_FILE="$OUTPUT_DIR/00_logs/pipeline.log"
SNAKE_FILE="$REPO_DIR/workflow/Snakefile.py"
CONFIG_FILE="$REPO_DIR/config/config.yml"

cd $REPO_DIR
```

**Bash script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# activate conda env
source activate pipeline_env

# run the pipeline
snakemake --cores --snakefile snakefile=$SNAKE_FILE --configfile snakefile config_file=$CONFIG_FILE \
--config output_dir=$OUTPUT_DIR fastq_dir=$FASTQ_DIR anc_dir=$ANC_DIR ref_fasta=$REF_FASTA\
--use-conda --conda-prefix="$HOME/.snakemake/conda"

echo -e "\nDONE!\n"
```

**Part of snakefile:**

```
import os
import json
from datetime import datetime


# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Define Constants ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #

# discover input files using path from run config
SAMPLES = list(set(glob_wildcards(f"{config['fastq_dir']}/{{sample}}_R1_001.fastq.gz").sample))

# read output dir path from run config
OUTPUT_DIR = config['output_dir']

# Project name and date for bam header
SEQID='pipeline_align'


# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Begin Pipeline ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #

# https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v7.14.0/tutorial/basics.html#step-7-adding-a-target-rule 
rule all:
    input:
        f'{OUTPUT_DIR}/DONE.txt'


# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Set Up Reference Files ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #

#
# export the current run configuration in JSON format
#
rule export_run_config:
    output:
        path=f"{OUTPUT_DIR}/00_logs/00_run_config.json"
    run:
        with open(output.path, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(dict(config), outfile, indent=4)


#
# make a list of discovered samples
#
rule list_samples:
    output:
        f"{OUTPUT_DIR}/00_logs/00_sample_list.txt"
    shell:
        "echo -e '{}' > {{output}}".format('\n'.join(SAMPLES))


#
# copy the supplied reference genome fasta to the pipeline output directory for reference
#
rule copy_fasta:
    input:
        config['ref_fasta']
    output:
        f"{OUTPUT_DIR}/01_ref_files/{os.path.basename(config['ref_fasta'])}"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"


rule index_fasta:
    input:
        rules.copy_fasta.output
    output:
        f"{rules.copy_fasta.output}.fai"
    conda:
        'envs/main.yml'
    shell:
        "samtools faidx {input}"


rule create_ref_dict:
    input:
        rules.copy_fasta.output
    output:
        f"{rules.copy_fasta.output}".rstrip('fasta') + 'dict'
    conda:
        'envs/main.yml'
    shell:
        "picard CreateSequenceDictionary -R {input}"

#
# create a BWA index from the copied fasta reference genome
#
rule create_bwa_index:
    input:
        rules.copy_fasta.output
    output:
        f"{rules.copy_fasta.output}.amb",
        f"{rules.copy_fasta.output}.ann",
        f"{rules.copy_fasta.output}.bwt",
        f"{rules.copy_fasta.output}.pac",
        f"{rules.copy_fasta.output}.sa",
    conda:
        'envs/main.yml'
    shell:
        "bwa index {input}"
```

And then I start putting the ancestor and sample files through the pipeline. However, the problem occurs upstream of when the Snakefile gets executed. I've tried reinstalling the git repo, but to no avail. I've also tried echoing the file path in the bash script, but the Snakefile still wasn't able to be found. I am submitting the bash script to a cluster, and it fails almost immediately.

How do I make sure the Snakefile is recognized through the bash script?

**Error:**
assert v is not None
AssertionError

or

snakemake: error: argument --snakefile/-s: expected one argument

I am using mamba as a package manager.

Comment: `Config.yml` file may be run by `bash`. Then there should not be a whitespace
between `REF_FASTA` and `=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell call should be changed to this:

```bash
snakemake --cores --snakefile "$SNAKE_FILE" --configfile config_file ...
```

Where `...` is the rest of the command. The main problem is that `--snakefile` (or `-s`) expects a string path to the Snakefile without any further keywords. Similarly, `--configfile` does not expect further keywords.